# Would it be possible to run unix system as a docker linux image on top of Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, docker, solaris, scratch

I understand that is impossible to run a docker image of a certain OS on top of a host with a different kernel than the image because of the fact that Docker images use host kernel to work...

I'm wondering if it would be possible to run UNIX systems, such as Solaris 10/11 x86_64 on a Linux host, using a Linux kernel instead of is own UNIX kernel...

Any idea?

Comment: Remove docker from the question, it doesn't provide any virtualization for this since it's a shared kernel (application level isolation instead of OS level). That leaves the question, "can you run Solaris binaries on Linux?" For that you need an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

No, because to make systems calls, the executables in the container use the libraries that are embarked in the container, and these assume the availabity of specific kernel systems calls, with specific parameters, and so work only with the specific kernel family they have been written for.